# Increase Servicestack Concurrent Process

Tags: servicestack

I have following Service:

```
public class ServerApp : AppHostHttpListenerPoolBase
{
    public ServerApp() : base("Server", 500,
            typeof(TestService).Assembly)
        {

        }

        public override void Configure(Container container)
        {
            ThreadsPerProcessor = 50;
        }
    }

    public class TestService : Service
    {
        private readonly Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        public object Any(Hello hello)
        {
            _logger.Info("Received: " + hello.Name);
            var waitingMinutes = new Random().Next(1, 10);

            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(waitingMinutes));

            _logger.Info("Response: " + hello.Name);
            return new GoodBye(){Message = "Bye Bye " + hello.Name};
        }
    }
}
```

and I have simple test project to push Parallel request to the Service (and push all is ok), but Service only process 2 requests at a time. When a request has been processed, the next request should be processed.

How can I increase the concurrent process?

Answer (score 0):

ServiceStack's `AppHostHttpListenerPoolBase` does execute Service concurrently by executing Services on new ThreadPool Threads.

To demonstrate this I've created a stand-alone example which executes 50 concurrent requests sleeping between 30-60s that calls the stand-alone test based on your Example in [ConcurrencyTest.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/ConcurrencyTest.cs) calling this Service:

```
public class SleepTest : IReturn<SleepTestResponse>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int WaitingSecs { get; set; }
}

public class SleepTestResponse
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
}

public class TestConcurrencyService : Service
{
    public object Any(SleepTest request)
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(request.WaitingSecs));

        return new SleepTestResponse
        {
            Message = $"{request.Name} took {sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} secs",
        };
    }
}
```

Which is called with this client load test executing 50 concurrent requests waiting between 30-60s:

```
var rand = new Random();
var client = new JsonHttpClient(Config.AbsoluteBaseUri);
client.GetHttpClient().Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
long responsesReceived = 0;
long totalSecondsWaited = 0;
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
const int ConcurrentRequests = 50;

ConcurrentRequests.Times(i =>
{
    Interlocked.Increment(ref responsesReceived);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(async _ => {
        var request = new SleepTest {
            Name = $"Request {i+1}",
            WaitingSecs = rand.Next(30, 60),
        };
        Interlocked.Add(ref totalSecondsWaited, request.WaitingSecs);

        log.Info($"[{DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay}] Sending {request.Name} to sleep for {request.WaitingSecs} seconds...");

        try
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync(request);
            log.Info($"[{DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay}] Received {request.Name}: {response.Message}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error($"[{DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay}] Error Response: {ex.UnwrapIfSingleException().Message}", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref responsesReceived);
        }
    });
});
```

Which waits for all threads to finish with:

```
while (Interlocked.Read(ref responsesReceived) > 0)
{
    Thread.Sleep(10);
}

log.Info($"Took {sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} to execute {ConcurrentRequests} Concurrent Requests waiting a total of {totalSecondsWaited} seconds.");
```

Which results in:

> INFO: Took 246.4556327 to execute 50 Concurrent Requests waiting a total of 2228 seconds.

i.e a lot less than it would've taken if the requests weren't executed concurrently.

The [full log for all requests](https://pastebin.com/raw/ShiR5kEY) showing the requests were executed just marginally longer than the server was requested to wait for.

The 2 concurrency limit you're indicating suggests it's a http client connection limit per domain. You should make sure you're using a load testing tool that doesn't have these limits like [wrk](https://github.com/wg/wrk) or [apacahe bench](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html).

#### Use .NET Core for best performance

Note if you want maximum throughput for Self Hosting ServiceStack Services we recommend [running ServiceStack on .NET Core](http://docs.servicestack.net/netcore), preferably on the .NET Core runtime, but if you need to, you can also run [ServiceStack ASP.NET Core on the .NET Framework](http://docs.servicestack.net/netcore#run-aspnet-core-apps-on-the-net-framework).